# How to use formArrayName with a parent formGroup directive. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I try to update my recipe which has collection of ingredients(formArray) and i have problem with that because of formArray.

I have error on console:

```
ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive
```

When i update recipe without formArray(ingredients) it's working fine.

Could you give me a hint ?

It's my first time when i'm working with formArrays..

My code:

**Component.ts**

```js
    export class RecipeEditComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild('editForm') editForm: NgForm;
      recipe: IRecipe;
      photos: IPhoto[] = [];
      ingredients: IIngredient[] = [];
      uploader: FileUploader;
      hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
      baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
      
      currentMain: IPhoto;
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private recipeService: RecipeService,
        private toastr: ToastrService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loadRecipe();
        
      }
```

Html

```html
    <div class="container mt-4 border" *ngIf="recipe">
        <form #editForm="ngForm" id="editForm" (ngSubmit)="updateRecipe(recipe.id)" >
          <h5 class=" text-center mt-2">Recipe details:</h5>
            <div class="form-group mt-3">
              <label for="city">Name</label>
              <label for="city">{{recipe.id}}</label>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="recipe.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div formArrayName="ingredients"
                *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index;">
                <div formGroupName= {{i}} class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <app-text-input formControlName="name" [label]='"Name"' name="ingredient[i].name"></app-text-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <app-text-input formControlName="amount" [label]='"Amount"' [type]="'number'" name="ingredient[i].amount"></app-text-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <h5 class=" text-center mt-4">Description</h5>
            <angular-editor cols=100% rows="6" [placeholder]="'Your description'" [(ngModel)]="recipe.description"  name="description"></angular-editor>
        </form>  
    
        <h3 class="text-center">Photos</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2" *ngFor="let photo of recipe.recipePhotos">
            <img src="{{photo.url}}" class="img-thumbnail p-1" alt="">
            <div class="text-center">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mr-1 mb-2" 
            (click) = "setMainPhoto(photo)" 
            [disabled]="photo.isMain" 
            [ngClass] = "photo.isMain ? 'btn-danger active' : 'btn-secondary'"
            >Main</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger mb-2" 
              (click)="deletePhoto(photo.id)" >
              <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row justify-content-md-center mt-5 border">
        <div class="col col-sm-4">
          <div class="mt-4 text-center">
          Multiple
          <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple="true"  /><br/>
        
          Single
          <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-sm-6">
          <div ng2FileDrop
              [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
              (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
              [uploader]="uploader"
              class="card  bg-faded p-3 text-center mt-3 mb-3 my-drop-zone">
              <i class="fa fa-upload fa-3x"></i>
              Drop Photos Here
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-5" style="margin-bottom: 40px" *ngIf="uploader?.queue?.length">
      <h3 class="text-center">Upload queue</h3>
      <p>Queue length: {{ uploader?.queue?.length }}</p>
    
      <table class="table">
          <thead>
          <tr>
              <th width="50%">Name</th>
              <th>Size</th>
    
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of uploader.queue">
              <td><strong>{{ item?.file?.name }}</strong></td>
              <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5" nowrap>{{ item?.file?.size/1024/1024 | number:'.2' }} MB</td>
              <td *ngIf="uploader.options.isHTML5">      
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    
      <div>
          <div>
              Queue progress:
              <div class="progress mb-4" >
                  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': uploader.progress + '%' }"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.uploadAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.getNotUploadedItems().length">
              <span class="fa fa-upload"></span> Upload 
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.cancelAll()" [disabled]="!uploader.isUploading">
              <span class="fa fa-ban"></span> Cancel 
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-s"
                  (click)="uploader.clearQueue()" [disabled]="!uploader.queue.length">
              <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Remove 
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
        <button [disabled]="!editForm.dirty" form="editForm" class="btn btn-success btn-block mb-5 mt-5">Save changes</button>
      </div>
```

This is how my recipe looks like with properties:

[image]

Comment: You ingredients list is of type IIngredients and not a FormArray. You would need to populate the FormArray with FormGroups representing each ingredient.

Comment: It also looks like you are mixing TemplateDriven and Reactive Forms.

Comment: @CMR could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Why don't you just use template driven forms? You have most of the work set up for that anyways. There will be a bit more overhead to set up the kind of reactive forms you want to try.

Comment: I just don't know how to figure out with array inside my form..

Comment: `ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive` the error message is telling that wherever you are surfacing this template, it does not have access to the outer `formGroup`, you need to pass it the `formGroup`, so that it can access the `formArray`. Look at `controlContainer` directive.

Comment: @amyloula thank you for your answer but i have all in one component. I'm reading about controlContainer and i can see examples only for two components parent and child.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Description

The directive `formArrayName` is a **ReactiveForm** directive and for it to work you must have below satisfied

- Must have a parent `formGroup`
- You must have imported `ReactiveFormModule` in your module

### Solution

You may have to do some changes to implement this, see below

See [Demo On Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdvpnf)

```js
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  recipe = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test Recipe',
    ingredients: [{
      name: 'Chicken',
      amount: 5
    },
    {
      name: 'Pasta',
      amount: 50
    }],
    description: 'Test Description'
  }
  ngForm = this.fb.group({
    description: [this.recipe.description],
    name: [this.recipe.name],
    ingredients: this.fb.array(
      this.recipe.ingredients.map(
        ingredient => this.fb.group({
          name: [ingredient.name],
          amount: [ingredient.amount]
        })
      )
    )
  })
  updateRecipe() {

  }
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="ngForm" id="editForm" (ngSubmit)="updateRecipe()">
    <h5 class=" text-center mt-2">Recipe details:</h5>
    <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <label for="city">Name</label>
        <label for="city">{{recipe.id}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName='name'>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div formArrayName="ingredients" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index;">
                <div formGroupName={{i}} class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <app-text-input formControlName="name" [label]='"Name"' name="ingredient[i].name">
                        </app-text-input>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-6">
                        <app-text-input formControlName="amount" [label]='"Amount"' [type]="'number'"
                            name="ingredient[i].amount"></app-text-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h5 class=" text-center mt-4">Description</h5>
        <angular-editor cols=100% rows="6" [placeholder]="'Your description'" 
      formControlName='description'></angular-editor>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Code that you showed here is very similar to mine on my recipe-create.component. I understand what is going on here but i don't know how to pass formArray (ingredients) to my editForm. Could you tell me how to connect it with  @ViewChild('editForm') editForm: NgForm;?

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to achieve this using `formArrayName` in a `templateDrivenForm` but in the loop you can do something like `<input [(ngModel)]="ingredient[i].name" />`. just make sure to remove the  `formArrayName`  directive from the div element

Comment: I removed formArrayName directive and formGroupName and then in the console i'm getting following error.  TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. Maybe i should do that in different way?

Comment: Please reproduce on stackblitz

Comment: i can't reproduce that on stackblitz. I just need additional code to display and edit ingredients on my editForm.

Comment: Thanks for the summary and example. For `formArrayName` _Must have a parent formGroup_, I am able to have `<form [formGroup]="fg"><div formGroupName="fgn"><div formArrayName="fan">` Looks like `formGroupName` makes itself as a `formGroup` (or subform I called) implicitly. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using FormArrays in your template, try using NgModel for  input data-binding:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients; let i = index;">
  <div class="form-group col-6">
    <input [(ngModel)]="ingredient.name" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-6">
    <input [(ngModel)]="ingredient.amount" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But in my form i would like to update current data. To get current data i'm using property name = "value". When i have name = "ingredient.name" it is displaying the same ingredient name instead of others.. As you can see on screenshoot. I have 2 ingredients : Chicken and Pasta, and it only display pasta twice.